# Using regular expressions to get parts of file name

Tags: macos, unix, command, rename, mv

On Mac (OS X) I have a directory with many images named like this:

```
IMG_250x333_1.jpg
IMG_250x333_2.jpg
IMG_250x333_3.jpg
...
```

I need to rename all of them to:

```
IMG_1.jpg
IMG_2.jpg
IMG_3.jpg
...
```

I think using a UNIX command line with "mv" and a kind of regex would do the job, but I don't know how! Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if there's a IMG_111x333_1.jpg and also a IMG_444x222_1.jpg? You risk mangling/overwriting something...

But if that is what you want, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
   new=${f/_*_/_}
   echo mv "$f" $new
done
```

If you like what it is doing, remove the word `echo`.

Comment: Good question! I indeed have several directories for each image size and thought I will take the shell script and adapt it due to the pixel number in the file name. But if there is a general way of eliminating the numbers from the file name, I am happy!! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I like:

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\)250x333_\(.*\)/mv "&" "\1\2"/' | sh
```

- List the files with `ls`.
- Then, transform the filenames with `sed`, and generate a `mv` command. Note that the `&` in the `sed` command outputs the full input string.
- Finally, evaluate the `mv` command with `sh`

The nice thing about this approach is you can remove `| sh` and test that your regex is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I just realized that the files in one of my directories have a space in the name between underscore and "250", like this: "IMG_ 250x333_1.jpg". How would the regex then be? Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi again! I executed the command line without "sh"  as you mentioned, just to check the output. But in the output I get the whole original name like "IMG_250x333_1.jpg". And when I use "sh" I get the error message "sh: line 1: IMG_250x333-10.jpg: command not found". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I've added quotes to the `sed` replace command to handle spaces in file/directory names. If it's still not working, can you paste the output?